# Mostrar Índices en orden JAVA

Tags: java, array

Hola estoy aprendiendo java y no me sale el siguiente ejercicio:

Las 3 primeras salas proyectan en 3D, de modo que el precio de entrada es más caro.
Así que ahora tienes que guardar el precio de entrada para cada película.
Para ello usa una matriz, en lugar de un array, donde sigas almacenando el título
de cada película y además su correspondiente precio.

```
    String titulos[] = new String[7];
    titulos[0] = "Jumanji";
    titulos[1] = "Rapido y Furiosos";
    titulos[2] = "Harry Potter";
    titulos[3] = "El señor de los anillos";
    titulos[4] = "El Hobbit";
    titulos[5] = "El Reportero";
    titulos[6] = "El Cielo";
    
    int[] precios = new int[7];
    precios[0] = 5000;
    precios[1] = 5000;
    precios[2] = 5000;
    precios[3] = 2000;
    precios[4] = 2000;
    precios[5] = 2000;
    precios[6] = 2000;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < titulos.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < precios.length; j++){
            System.out.println("La pelicula es: "+titulos[i]+" Su precio:"+precios[j]);
        }
    }
```

Quiero que la salida del programa quede asi:
La pelicula es: Jumanji Su precio: 5000

y asi consecutivamente, gracias.

Comment: si lo array son del mismo tamaño solo necesitas usar 1 ciclo for y hacer uso del mismo indice en ambos arrays  `for(int i = 0; i < titulos.length; i++){System.out.println("La pelicula es: "+titulos[i]+" Su precio:"+precios[i]);}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

respondiendo a tu pregunta solo usa un for

```
for(int i = 0; i < titulos.length; i++){
    System.out.println("La pelicula es: "+titulos[i]+" Su precio:"+precios[i]);
}
```

Ahora, si esta bien que uses array pero que pasari si precio no tiene la misma cantidad de valores que tiene titulos, se genera un error.
Yo te recomendaria que uses un array de objeto en lugar de dos array, para eso inicias creando una clase objeto como la siguiente:

```
public class Peliculas{

    private String titulo = "";
    private Integer precio = 0;


    public Peliculas(String t, Integer p){
        titulo = t;
        precio = p;
    }

    public void printPelicula(){
        System.out.println("Pelicula: " + titulo + ", Precio" + precio);
    }
}
```

Esta clase menejaria la informacion de las peliculas, en este caso nombre y precio.

Para luego crear una lista de estos objetos, mas o menos asi

```
Peliculas[] pelis = new Peliculas[5];
pelis[0] = new Peliculas("Jumanji",5000 );
...
```

En donde llenaremos esta lista con objetos peliculas asi ya solo la recorremos y como este objeto tiene una funcion llamada printPeliculas , basta que la mandemos a llamar para desplegarla

```
for(int i = 0; i<  pelis.length; i++){
    pelis[i].printPelicula();
}
```

esta solucion te ayuda a mantener toda la informacion guardada en una sola lista a su vez en caso de que quieras agregar, por ejemplo, una propiedad de genero, entonces el mismo objeto se encargaria de manejarlo ya no tendrias que estar usando mas variables.

Answer (score 0):

Las dimensiones de ambos arreglos son iguales por lo tanto, si el indice de `titulos` siempre corresponde con el de `precios`, realiza en un bucle la obtenciòn de datos con la misma variable que contiene el indice.

```
String titulos[] = new String[7];
titulos[0] = "Jumanji";
titulos[1] = "Rapido y Furiosos";
titulos[2] = "Harry Potter";
titulos[3] = "El señor de los anillos";
titulos[4] = "El Hobbit";
titulos[5] = "El Reportero";
titulos[6] = "El Cielo";

int[] precios = new int[7];
precios[0] = 5000;
precios[1] = 5000;
precios[2] = 5000;
precios[3] = 2000;
precios[4] = 2000;
precios[5] = 2000;
precios[6] = 2000;

for(int i = 0; i < titulos.length; i++){
     System.out.println("La pelicula es: "+titulos[i]+" Su precio:"+precios[i]);
}
```

la salida serìa:

```
La pelicula es: Jumanji Su precio:5000
La pelicula es: Rapido y Furiosos Su precio:5000
La pelicula es: Harry Potter Su precio:5000
La pelicula es: El señor de los anillos Su precio:2000
La pelicula es: El Hobbit Su precio:2000
La pelicula es: El Reportero Su precio:2000
La pelicula es: El Cielo Su precio:2000
```